# How to avoid screen flickering when showing form with user drawn controls?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, user-controls, onpaint

So the [transparent background problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/214215/user-drawn-controls-are-using-the-previous-forms-background) is solved.  Now, every time I show the form (or have to have it repainted), I get a lot of flickering.  Is there any way I can not update the screen until the paint event is complete, or any other way to stop the 1/2 second of flickering and flashing while all the objects are being painted?

**ANSWER**: Double buffering is the way to go.  I was already double buffering on the control, but it has to be set on the form.  I though double buffering only worked when you were subclassing OnPaint yourself.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Did you try setting the [DoubleBuffered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/220100/how-do-i-enable-double-buffering-of-a-control-using-c-window-forms) property for the form?

Answer (score 5):

Double Buffering might help, another thing you might want to try is:

SuspendLayout();

dostuffhere...

ResumeLayout();

Comment: DoubleBuffered _increases_ resource requirements, but is more likely to be effective.  Suspend/ResumeLayout() _reduce_ resource requirements, but are less likely to be effective.

Answer (score 2):

Set the DoubleBuffered Property on the form.